# Dev SP 2013 server is filled with 6481 and 6398 errors

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error

The dev server is filled with errors **6398**:

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CustomDictionaryDeploymentJobDefinition
>   (ID 339e26fd-56be-4f9e-b9bc-50c32d42b9ee) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0FF1CE15-0005-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070422 The service cannot be started, either because it is
>   disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070422).

And **6481** :

> Application Server job failed for service instance
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance
>   (f9677bce-935a-4d4f-97b4-8c7c32672676).
>
> Reason: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0FF1CE15-0005-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070422 The service cannot be started, either because it is
>   disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070422).
>
> Technical Support Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80070422): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with
>   CLSID {0FF1CE15-0005-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the
>   following error: 80070422 The service cannot be started, either
>   because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated
>   with it. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070422).    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Gatherer.get_AdminObject()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Gatherer.ProvisionGlobalProperties()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean
>   isAdministrationServiceJob)

Could anyone point me to the correct direction. We don't care for search services(yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is permission problem on the Osearch in DCOM.

- Open Start Menu > Administrative Tools > Component Services Tool
- Drill Down and Expand DCOM Config
- Navigate to the OSearch15,Right Click Properties
- Select the Security Tab
- Add the Network Service Account to Local and Activation Permissions
- Add the Network Service Account to Access Permissions
- Restart the Office SharePoint Server Search Service

I hope this will fix the problem.

Comment: It was OK - i.e. the network service was there. Yet the sharepoint server search 15 is disabled - we don't actually need it.

Comment: If it is disabled n you don't need it then ignore these errors.